# C# listbox & excel how to delete info in excel?

Tags: c#, excel

So I have winform with listbox and button1(update) so when i press button1 it opens excel document finds info that I need and populates listbox.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;



namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string FName = @"c:\TEST\data.xlsx";
            var excelApp = new Excel.Application();
            excelApp.Visible = true;

            Excel.Workbook excelbk = excelApp.Workbooks._Open(FName,
               Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
               Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
               Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

            Excel.Worksheet xlSht = (Excel.Worksheet)excelbk.Worksheets["Sheet1"];

            //find Column Number
            //Now find Test in Row 1
            Excel.Range column = (Excel.Range)xlSht.Columns[1, Type.Missing];
            string FindWhat = "name";
            bool MatchCase = true;

            Excel.Range FindResults = column.Find(FindWhat, Type.Missing,
                Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues, Excel.XlLookAt.xlWhole,
                Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByColumns, Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext,
                MatchCase, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);


            int colNumber = FindResults.Column;

            //Get Last Row of Data
            Excel.Range xlRange = (Excel.Range)xlSht.get_Range("A" + xlSht.Rows.Count, Type.Missing);
            int LastRow = xlRange.get_End(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlDirection.xlUp).Row;

            //start update
            listBox1.BeginUpdate();

            //read data into form
            string CellData;
            for (int RowCount = 2; RowCount <= LastRow; RowCount++)
            {
                xlRange = (Excel.Range)xlSht.Cells[RowCount, colNumber];
                CellData = (string)xlRange.Text;
                listBox1.Items.Add(CellData);

            }

            //end update
            listBox1.EndUpdate();

            object SaveChanges = (object)false;
            excelbk.Close(SaveChanges, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
            excelApp.Quit();
            excelApp = null;
        }

    }
}
```

What I want to do now,  delete button, so that user selects one of the names and for delete button delete all info in row with selected name for example cell A2 contains name that is shown in listbox, when user hits delete button it deletes all info in row 2.

Answer (score 1):

You can find use the WorksheetFunction.Match function to get the row that a user is on, and from there you should be able to delete that row.

```
double Match(
    Object Arg1, 
    Object Arg2, 
    Object Arg3
)
```

Parameters

Arg1
Type: System.Object
Lookup_value - the value you use to find the value you want in a table.

Arg2
Type: System.Object
Lookup_array - a contiguous range of cells containing possible lookup values. Lookup_array must be an array or an array reference.

Arg3
Type: System.Object
Match_type - the number -1, 0, or 1. Match_type specifies how Microsoft Excel matches lookup_value with values in lookup_array.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.worksheetfunction.match.aspx

Extra stuff:
In the spirit of being more helpful, let's say your excel sheet has column headers in the first row, and the names in the first column, starting at row 2. So something like,

> Row 1: Name
>
> Row 2: Steve
>
> Row 3: John
>
> Row 4: Adam
>
> Row 5: Randy

If you used `Match("Adam", A2:A5, 0)`, the returned value would be 3, because within your range of A2:A5, it was the 3rd row, so the row you'll actually want to delete is 4. Gotta account for these kinds of things. You could include A1 in your range, and that could work in most cases.

Comment: If it works, would you mind marking this as the answer? And you're welcome.